# Создание функции ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Допустим у меня есть данные

```
data=data.frame(s=c(10,13,17,8),
                pr=c("a","b","a","b"),
                m=c(rep(as.Date('01.01.2015','%d.%m.%Y'),2), rep(as.Date('01.02.2015','%d.%m.%Y'),2)),
                pr2=c("c","d","d","c"))
```

И я пытаюсь создать функцию которая рисует `ggplot` в зависимости от `col1` - колонка по которой нужно делать `fill`.

```
plot_function=function(col1){...}
```

Функция должна возвращать `ggplot`

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = as.factor(m), y = s/2,fill=col1 ,ymax = max(s/2)*1.1)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(y=s/4,label=paste(round(s/2,3),"%")),position = position_dodge(.9)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) format(as.Date(x), "%m/%y")) + 
  xlab("m")
```

где `fill` переменная внутри функции.

Пробовал сделать нечто подобное используя `aes_string()` вместо `aes()` но не знаю как совместить операции над переменными например `s/2` и `aes_string()`.

Так же смотрел `lazyeval` , который я использовал в подобных ситуациях когда делал функции из `dplyr`, но не смог понять как его тут применить.

в `dplyr` я делал вот так

```
group=function(data,...){

    dat1=group_by_(data,.dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...))
    return(dat1)
  }
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Вынесите все преобразования за пределы `ggplot`, а внутри `ggplot` уже `aes_string`.

Comment: @ArtemKlevtsov Спасибо , я уже думал об этом других вариантов нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На основании комментария @ArtemKlevtsov и свои догадок на этот счет в итоге сделал вот так

```
gr_plot=function(data_12,nm){

  i=which(colnames(data_12)==nm) 

  data_12$var=data_12$s/2
  data_12$m=as.factor(data_12$m)
  j=which(colnames(data_12)=="m")
  k=which(colnames(data_12)=="var")

  return(  ggplot(data = data_12, aes_string(x = names(data_12)[j], y =  names(data_12)[k],fill=names(data_12)[i]))+
    geom_bar(position = "dodge",stat="identity")+
    geom_text(aes(y=s/4,label=paste(round(s/2,3),"%")),position = position_dodge(.9)) + 
    scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) format(as.Date(x), "%m/%y")) + 
    xlab("m")

  )
}
```

соответственно достаточно просто нарисовать в различных разрезах

```
gr_plot(data,"pr")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
gr_plot(data,"pr2")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если у кого то есть идеи как сделать нечто подобное через `lazyeval` было бы интересно увидеть.